# Encode/Decode CMYK Images from Flash Player

Tags: actionscript-3, rgb, cmyk, argb

I'm currently working on an image editor in Flash Player, and I need to be able to export CMYK images to my server. I'm completely new to color profiles and the like, and I was wondering how I could accomplish this. I am pretty sure all images in Flash Player are ARGB, so is there a way to convert the values properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to read a little bit about the JPEG format - I mean, not just "JPEGs are used in XYZ, because XYZ." - I mean like the actual format down to the bytes. Because I don't really know if anybody did an actual library for that, maybe you will have to do it.

You need a library that understands the JPEG format and knows whether it is CMYK or RGB, and then to actually convert it (that includes the CMYK-RGB math).

It is not included in the flash built-in libs.